Error in Swirl Programming exercise 'functions' for R
Stuck at the 55% completion exercise. Trying to use the evaluate function defined as follows:
evaluate <- function(func, dat){
 func(dat)
}

Stuck at this next exercise:
Let's take your new evaluate() function for a spin! Use evaluate to find the standard deviation of the vector c(1.4,
| 3.6, 7.9, 8.8).

My input is
> evaluate(sd, c(1.4, 3.6, 7.9, 8.8))

I keep getting the error
Error in func(dat) : could not find function "func"

I've tried restarting swirl and using the following line of code, but to no avail.
> evaluate(func = sd, dat = c(1.4,3.6,7.9,8.8))

Please help.

Works for me. Did you check if evaluate is in the Global Environment? run lsf.str() to be sure

Yes it is. I've tried evaluate(mean, c(1.4, 3.6, 7.9, 8.8)) and gotten the correct answer, it's just standard deviation that this is not working for, for some reason and I can't proceed further.

does sd(NA) work?

what is the result if you just call sd : do you get the sd function or another object?

I got this function (x, na.rm = FALSE)  sqrt(var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x),      na.rm = na.rm)) <bytecode: 0x10d8587f0> <environment: namespace:stats>

this is the standard sd function. Does evaluate(sd, c(1.4, 3.6, 7.9, 8.8)) still return the same error?

Yes, it's still not working

Then I'm stuck ;-), hopefully someone comes with another idea.

The most probable reason is that sd function has been overwritten :
evaluate <- function(func, dat){
  func(dat)
}

# Overwrite sd
sd <- NA

evaluate(sd, c(1.4, 3.6, 7.9, 8.8))
Error in func(dat) : could not find function "func"

# Delete overwrite
rm(sd)

evaluate(sd, c(1.4, 3.6, 7.9, 8.8))
#> [1] 3.514138


I can run sd <- NA and see that sd is now an object in my global environment, and sd(1:5) still works as expected, even though func(sd, 1:5) gives the error. Can someone explain more why that happens?

@JonSpring, this looks like a namespace issue. evaluate seems to look in local environment only, whereas when you use sd as a function which is masked in the local environment, R uses stats::sd
